# Scala - Spark - How can I get a new dataframe with distinct values of a dataframe column and the first date of this distinct values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark Dataframe with the following schema:

```
________________________
|id   | no  | date      |
|1    | 123 |2018/10/01 |
|2    | 124 |2018/10/01 |
|3    | 123 |2018/09/28 |
|4    | 123 |2018/09/27 |
```

...
What I want is to have a new DataFrame with the following data:

```
___________________
| no  | date      |
| 123 |2018/09/27 |
| 124 |2018/10/01 |
```

Can someone help me on this?:) Thank you!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome,

you can try below Code :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy($"no").orderBy($"date".asc)
val Resultdf = df.withColumn("rownum", row_number.over(w))
     .where($"rownum" === 1).drop("rownum","id")

Resultdf.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----------+
| no|      date|
+---+----------+
|124|2018/10/01|
|123|2018/09/27|
+---+----------+
```

Comment: Why the -1 if I may inquire?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it by using the rank (https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) on dataframe with spark sql:

use `registerTempTable` on `sparkContext` such as `df_temp_table`

Make this query:

```
    select dftt.*,  
    dense_rank() OVER ( PARTITION BY dftt.no ORDER BY dftt.date DESC) AS Rank from 
    df_temp_table as dftt
```

you will get this dataframe:

```
|id | no | date       | rank 
|1  | 123 |2018/10/01 | 1
|2  | 124 |2018/10/01 | 1
|3  | 123 |2018/09/28 | 2
|4  | 123 |2018/09/27 | 3
```

on this df you can now filter the rank column by 1